# Extract Images PDF Apache Tika 1.15 command line

Tags: java, python, shell, pdf, apache-tika

I am trying to use ApacheTika command line tool to extract images from a pdf.

I have a python server, and I don't wanna rebuild it in Java just to use Tika. My solution was to use the command line tools to extract images from the pdf and then read it from python. The problem is that when I send the `--extract` or `-z` command to the command line tool, it doesn't extract the images from the pdf.

I know it's possible to extract the images from this pdf because I was using `pdfimages` before and it was extracting correctly those images.

Can anyone help me with this issue.

Israel

Comment: Can you wait a couple of days? Tika 1.16 has it as standard

Comment: Sir, I am using apache-tika-server 1.16 jar and I still cannot extract the images from the pdf. Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: If you use the Tika App then it's on as standard. In the Tika Server, you'll need to need to pass a custom HTTP header with your request to enable `pdfParserConfig.setExtractInlineImages`